# How can I remove a specific security user from all databases on a server matching a given name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a setup similar to this:

> - SQL-2005-SRVR
>
>   - Security
>
>     - **MYAPP_LOGIN**
>   - Database1
>
>     - Security
>
>       - **MYAPP_USER**
>       - OTHERUSER
>   - Database2
>
>     - Security
>
>       - OTHERUSER
>   - Database3
>
>     - Security
>
>       - **MYAPP_USER**
>       - TESTUSER
>   - Database4
>
>     - Security
>
>       - **MYAPP_USER**
>   - Database5
>
>     - Security
>
>       - OTHERUSER
>       - TESTUSER

I am trying to figure out how to write a SQL script that will remove all users matching `MYAPP_USER` from all databases on the server. I am not familiar with how to iterate over multiple databases from within a single script, or even how to query if the user exists within that database. Additionally, I am unsure what context/catalog this script would be run from - `master`, `msdb`, `model`?

In the above example, `Database1`, `Database3`, and `Database4` would all have their users named `MYAPP_USER` dropped.

I also need to remove the login from the server itself, but I know that's as easy as `DROP LOGIN MYAPP_LOGIN`.

The script will be run as a server administrator, so permissions are not an issue.

How would I go about removing all of the users in each database that match the name `MYAPP_USER`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
begin try
  drop user [<put a name in here>]
  print ''did drop at ?''
end try
begin catch
  print ''did not drop at ?''
end catch
'
GO
```

Way easier.  And you can tell where it worked.

Comment: Loved this solution, output made it easy to tell where it dropped and where it didn't, great!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the undocumented procedure `sp_MSforeachdb`, check for the existence of the database user by joining `master.sys.server_principals` to `sys.database_principals` (and filtering on the sql server login name), then drop the user if found.  The user linked to `MYAPP_LOGIN` will get dropped, even if it is not specifically named `MYAPP_USER`

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
    DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Tsql = ''''

    SELECT @Tsql = ''DROP USER '' + d.name
    FROM sys.database_principals d
    JOIN master.sys.server_principals s
        ON s.sid = d.sid
    WHERE s.name = ''MYAPP_LOGIN''

    EXEC (@Tsql)
'
GO
```

**Note**
If the SQL Server login is created from Windows, replace `MYAPP_LOGIN` with `YourDomain\\ADUser` (yes, it's a double back-slash).

Comment: Perfect - this is just what I needed! What a shame it's undocumented, this is a really powerful built-in procedure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand wrote a customized version of `sp_MSforeachdb`.  If you find yourself using the tactic frequently, you may want to check out [Aaron's version](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)